# BIRT .xlsx file is damaged in Linux Environment While working good in Windows Environment

Tags: linux, apache-poi, birt, xlsx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roM6w.png)*Hi,
    I'm using BIRT verison 4_5_0. I've deployed application in my development windows environment and I could generate report with chart in .xlsx format. It's working fine in windows environment. But my production environment is Linux. If I generate report in Linux environment then the returned output is file damaged. What's the reason for the issue? Should I include any additional .jars? Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still new but I know that XLSX is a Microsoft extension. If I'm not wrong, on Linux, you can have a different behavior. So, when I run report on windows, I generate it for XLSX format but for Linux, I generate it for ODS (libre office and not microsoft office).

I don't remember if you need to add an emitter (JAR) or if it's in eclipse by default.But this is the link that explain : https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/arctorus-xlsx-xls-ods-csv-birt-emitter

Be free to ask if you need help with the emitters.